# Why does Rust require a C++ toolchain to produce a Rust binary, while languages like Go do not have this requirement?

Tags: c++, go, rust, toolchain, build-tools

Compiling a Rust file with `rustc foo.rs` fails if I don't have a C++ toolchain installed. But when compiling a Go program, such a toolchain is not required. Why is that?

Comment: Note: The Rust community is working on a Rust backend (cranelift) as an alternative (but not a replacement) to LLVM. Even then, though, the rustc compiler would still depend on a libc implementation being present. I think steed (embedded) and relibc (Redox) are about re-implementing the libc in Rust, but not clear where they are.

Comment: I think this question is either too broad either too small, basically the answer is because rustc require it. Long answer is just too broad.

Comment: The answer for Rust is that by default it compiles by linking statically to the libc. I wonder if the C toolchain must be present if you use the flag for the dynamic linking. I know too few about Go to answer, though.

Comment: @Stargateur if you're new to programming, compiler infrastructure can be quite mysterious. Asking why one seemingly unrelated depends on another is a perfectly fair question. Seems programming related to me as well, but there's so many estoeric SE these days and people love to split hairs.

Comment: @Svend I didn't say it was off topic, I said it's too broad. Explain "compiler infrastructure" is too broad.

Comment: @Stargateur you missed the whole point, I wanted to know why Go does not require a separate toolchain like Rust does - simple, not *why* Rust requires a Toolchain - that info is already available in Google.

Comment: I feel that the downgrade in my post rating is unfair.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR: Because everyone has a C toolchain.**

*Slight correction: rustc does not require a C++ toolchain, it only requires a C toolchain. Notably, rustc created binaries only depend on `libc` (or equivalent), not on `libstdc++` (or equivalent).*

---

As Go demonstrated, it is possible to not require a C toolchain. You only need to re-implement its functionality:

- You need to implement your own linker, respecting the target platform format.
- You need to implement your own libc (aka OS layer).

There are advantages to doing so, such as possibly faster compilation or easier cross-compiling, however there is a cost in doing the implementation, and *it's easy to [get things wrong](https://marcan.st/2017/12/debugging-an-evil-go-runtime-bug/)*.

---

The Rust community preferred to put more effort into the language than in the toolchain, and therefore reusing the stock toolchain was easier. Specifically, rustc will require a platform linker (`ld` on Unix) and platform equivalent to `libc`.

This is not a core design principle, it's just a pragmatic approach, and there are projects to cut down on these dependencies:

- Using [lld](https://lld.llvm.org/) rather than ld would allow shipping a single linker with rustc which can target all platforms.
- Using [cranelift](https://github.com/CraneStation/cranelift) as an alternative backend could also remove the dependency on ld.
- The Redox project is working on [relibc](https://github.com/redox-os/relibc), a portable Rust implementation of the `libc` API.

Those are all work in progress, and in the meantime rustc will require a C toolchain. Furthermore, even in the foreseeable future, I would expect rustc to require a C toolchain for targets not yet covered by any Rust toolchain, just so you can use the target without waiting for some hypothetical development.

Comment: Maybe the OP is talking about a C++ toolchain because he uses a Windows OS. It seems that there is not a clear difference in it between the C and C++ toolchains.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios: Possibly. I clarified this is a different requirement in general, and a much less onerous one.

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuM. your answer on the Go part is all I was looking for, and thanks for explaining the part on Rust as well.